# How to remove sourcecode from json file which is generated by compodoc

Tags: angular, typescript, compodoc

i just found compodoc, a documentation tool for angular projects. It works and can create a json file which contains all information about the project. However i want to get rid of all sourcecode information in the file, i need to do this for further processing of the information to the database.

I download the source code of compodoc in github, and modified it and build it.
It gives me an index.js and index-cli.js file after the build. But i don't know what to do with those files.

Does anybody have an idea how to use them or knows how to remove sourcecode from json file?

Thanks.

Comment: Just guessing, but did you try the `--disableSourceCode` argument when running `compodoc`? Information on this, and other arguments, can be found [here](https://compodoc.app/guides/usage.html).

Comment: Yes. I did that. But this option only disableds the source code tab if you display the documentation as html pages. In my case i generate json file.

Comment: Ah I see. Unfortunately, from a brief look over the source, it looks like for the JSON export pretty much dumps the pre-prepared objects without processing, so there aren't any flags to affect this. However, I noticed a GitHub issue related to this has been raised: https://github.com/compodoc/compodoc/issues/785